# Getting CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied while trying to launch the emulator programmatically from Java Appium code

Tags: java, android-emulator, appium, processbuilder, access-denied

I am running a Java Appium code where I want to start my emulator programmatically for which I am using the Process builder.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

Here is the code snippet:

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class EmulatorRunner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String emulatorPath = "C:\Users\nithyashri.raov\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator";

```
    // You might need to adjust the emulator name and other parameters based on your setup
    String[] command = {emulatorPath, "-avd", "your_avd_name"};
    
    try {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        processBuilder.directory(new File(emulatorPath).getParentFile());
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        
        // Optional: You can capture the output of the emulator if needed
        // InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        // String line;
        // while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //     System.out.println(line);
        // }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}